# Updating RstDocument in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I used the RstDocument to show the output text, I like to frequently update the text in RstDocument. But, the updating is not working

```
class fi(App)
 def build(self):
    self.title = "TOOL"
    self.root = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
    
    self.out2 = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal")
    self.document = """

TOOLs \n

"""
    self.sh ="""
    
    .. _myreff:
    
    @#$


"""
    self.document += self.sh
    
    self.rst = RstDocument(text=self.document, colors={'paragraph':'ce5c00ff', 'background':'000000ff'},)
    if(Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.rst.goto, 'myreff'), 4)):
        print("build_good")
    self.rst.render()
    self.out2.add_widget(self.rst)
    self.root.add_widget(self.out2)
    return self.root

 def job_process(self, show_text=""""""):
    self.sh ="""
    
    .. _myreff:
    
    @#$


"""

    if(self.sh in self.document):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.document = self.document.replace(self.sh, "")
        print(self.document)
        time.sleep(2)
    self.document = self.document + """ \n """ 
    self.document = self.document + show_text + self.sh
    print(self.document)
    time.sleep(2)
    return()
```

When some calculations are finished, I called the function `job_process("some text")` to update the `self.document` to print the updated output. But It is not updating. I do not know what is the issue. There is no warnings, no errors from RstDocument()
Thanks

Comment: Avoid using `time.sleep` in Kivy applications. [Kivy: Events & Properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#main-loop)

Comment: @ikolim, I removed the time.sleep, still rst document is not updating... Could you please help me